# cypher - Handling rows of different sizes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the Movielens dataset to build a prototype recommender system. But in order to import the categories for each movie, I need to handle rows of different sizes in cypher.
Eg

```
;1;Toy Story (1995);Animation|Children's|Comedy
;2;Jumanji (1995);Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
;3;Grumpier Old Men (1995);Comedy|Romance
;4;Waiting to Exhale (1995);Comedy|Drama
;5;Father of the Bride Part II (1995);Comedy
```

Each of the movie has one or more categories. How do I handle this type of row?

I thought about changing the delimiter to "|" and then somehow iterating from row[3] to row[n].

But how do I know 'n', and how to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With delimiter |, you can split the categories and then merge each one. 
For example-

```
UNWIND split(row.categories, "|" ) AS category
MERGE (c:Category { name: category })
MERGE (movie)-[:CATEGORY]->(c)
```

Comment: I get the undefined 'row' error when I run this query-
LOAD CSV from "file:/C:/1m/movies.csv" AS row
unwind split(row[3],"|") AS genre
merge (c:Genres { name: genre  })
merge (m:Movies { MovieID: row[1] })
MERGE (m)-[:HAS_GENRE]->(c)

Comment: Add a WITH row: LOAD CSV from "..." AS row fieldterminator ";" WITH row unwind...